# display in another window a linked table from a datagrid row

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml, datagrid

i would like to display the table Study for one row of the table Employee.
 I have my datagrid and a button ("detail") when users select a row and press the detail button a new window pop up and show the table study of this enployee.

Thank you forward.

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    private List<Employee> _lstEmp;


    public List<Employee> LstEmp
    {
        get { return _lstEmp = _lstEmp?? getEmp(); }
        set { _lstEmp = value; OnPropertyChanged("LstEmp"); }
    }

    private List<Employee> getEmp()
    {
        using (vitaeEntities Db = new vitaeEntities())
        {
            return  Db.Employee.ToList();
                //.Select(e => new {fName=e.First_Name, lName = e.Last_Name, })
        }
    }
  private void btn_Detail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (vitaeEntities db = new vitaeEntities())
        {
            int empId = ((Employee)dtgrid_Emp.SelectedItem).ID_EMployee;
            Employee query = db.Employee.Where(em => em.ID_EMployee == empId).Single();


        }            
       detail wDetail = new detail();
        wDetail.Show();
```

on the other window i use thise

```
    private List<Study> getStudy()
    {
        using (vitaeEntities Db = new vitaeEntities())
        {

            return Db.Study.Where(st => st.Employee.ID_EMployee == empId)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

But empID is not reach because its define in the main window so i try to get this variable reachable to my other window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the value into your second window.

```
int empId;

using (vitaeEntities db = new vitaeEntities())
{
    empId = ((Employee)dtgrid_Emp.SelectedItem).ID_EMployee;
    ...
}

detail wDetail = new detail(empId);
wDetail.Show();
```

Then inside your second window:

```
public partial class detail : Window
{
    private int empId;

    public detail(int empId)
    {
        this.empId = empId;
        ...
    }

    private List<Study> getStudy()
    {
        using (vitaeEntities Db = new vitaeEntities())
        {
            return Db.Study.Where(
                st => st.Employee.ID_EMployee == empId).ToList();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: vs tell me that Employee is a type and use like a variable when i pass the value in .show

Comment: I m not sure you understand what i wnated to do i m sorry but that does not help me well it might be but i dont think  i have knowledge to do this with your help...,
anyway i have a variabe named "(int)empID" in my main window and i d like to have acces to the same variable in the second window this variable is the row i d like to display the other table.
I have acces to all collection in both windo due to "this.DataContext = this;" Any other good idea ?? :D

Comment: @DavidHuy, not to be a ranting person, but the answer you received is a perfect demonstration of passing parameters through the constructor which is exactly what you are referring to. When the data is in the mainwindow, you cannot simply access it from anywhere.

Comment: @Schuere any advice as is importance but i m a realy new developer so sometimes there 're things i don't get i change m y code but it not working much more. Now with the new constructor the detail window is blank ...

Comment: i just add initializecompenant() and the stuff are there but stil i don't get the things with the constructor

Comment: i had trouble in my xaml but i actualy add new constructor and giving him the datacontext. But i still got no result for the detail of the selected employe i might have problem in my database , i ll try to check with the brak point and i coming bak

Comment: I put the brak point in front off the cration of the window and empId worth 0 but in the lambda expression it worth 1 so it doesnt keep the value in the main windows..

Comment: sorry it ok its value is to 1 but still nothing appears in the detail window i mispelled empId

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

change

```
private void btn_Detail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (vitaeEntities db = new vitaeEntities())
    {
        int empId = ((Employee)dtgrid_Emp.SelectedItem).ID_EMployee;
        Employee query = db.Employee.Where(em => em.ID_EMployee == empId).Single();

        //set the call of your detail inside the using or set empId out of the using
        detail wDetail = new detail(empId);
        wDetail.Show();

    }            

}
```

in your detail create a new property

```
public int EmpId{get;set;}
```

Create a new Constructor

```
public detail(int empID)
{
 EmpId = empId;
}
```

change the code in your detail

private List getStudy()
    {
        using (vitaeEntities Db = new vitaeEntities())
        {

```
        return Db.Study.Where(st => st.Employee.ID_EMployee == EmpId) //empId => EmpId
            .ToList();
    }
}
```